# AngularJS : How do optimize the below if/else statement in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do i optimize/reduce line of code of the below if/else statements of angularjs

```
if($scope.menuActive === true)
  { 
       $rootScope.menuActiveStatus = true;
  }

  else {
       $rootScope.menuActiveStatus=false;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You mean inline?

```
$rootScope.menuActiveStatus = $scope.menuActive === true;
```

You can also set any other value based on the `$scope.menuActive === true` condition (Just for example):

```
$rootScope.menuActiveStatus = $scope.menuActive === true ? "YES!" : "NO :("; // Ternary operator example
```